# How to convert international characters like è, à etc to normal character in excel using c# (I am using ClosedXML)

Tags: encode, closedxml

I am comparing two sheets using ClosedXML in c#. But i need to first convert the international characters to normal characters and then continue with comparing. I am not getting the encode part. Kindly help me out.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this and where are you failing?

Comment: If for instance there is a field 'Name' in both the sheets with values as 'Allen' and 'Allèn'. Now i have two data table where my sheet data are present. While using Equal() to compare both the value, it is returning false. So i am not sure how to convert the character 'è' to 'e'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove diacritics (accents) from a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: This question is not related to ClosedXML, but is purely a C# question about comparing accented characters to their non-accented versions.